# Was Rey's memory wiped?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, Rey can't remember why and by whom she was left on Jakku, but she was also very young.

**Was her memory wiped?** or was she just too young to remember?

She seems to have forgotten everything important; her parents, friends, why she's there, who left her there, *everything*.

Comment: We don't know from existing canon. Plausible but not nearly confirmed

Comment: I wonder if it's even possible to wipe's someone's memory.

Comment: in EU canon, definitely. Kyp Durron wiped out that scientist's memory so she couldn't recreate SunCrusher.

Comment: If only _she_ could be wiped from _our_ memory ...

Answer (score 8):

The implication is that she was simply too young to recall anything distinctly. She has *some* memory of being left, but a combination of the trauma of the event and post-traumatic stress (life on Jakku is *hard*) seem to have blocked out whatever was left. **There's no evidence that her memory has been tampered with.**

> *Absentmindedly, Rey mimicked the mother’s loving gesture, softly
> stroking the salvage in her hand. **Rey had no memory of her parents.**
> She didn’t know why they had taken her to Jakku, or why they had left
> her there. For all she knew, they were long dead. Yet Rey couldn’t
> help hoping that one day a transport would arrive and her parents
> would walk down the ship’s ramp and back into her life.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Rey's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey%27s_Story)</sup></sub>

Notably, a later (also canon) story conflicts with this. She remembers some information about her parent, including their names.

> Just a few hours earlier, they dared to think that maybe . . . they’d
> made it? They’d gotten out of their homestead, their all-purpose house
> droid, handcrafted from more scrap and salvage, sacrificing itself as
> it led the hunters astray. Then they found the ship (truth be told,
> they had long ago earmarked it for such a day—a day they hoped would
> never come). Launched it, just themselves, a bag of toys and books and
> a handful of credits, the clothes on their backs. Pointed the
> navi­computer along a vector that would take them way out of range (so
> they hoped). And buckled in for the ride.
>
> But now? The ship had barely survived the initial trip. Escaping to
> Wild Space had been a desperate move, but was far from the endgame. It
> was supposed to be where they could hide, just for a while, take the
> time to make a plan and plot a course.
>
> Those options now seemed decidedly more limited as they floated
> adrift. They’d escaped Jakku, only to . . . what? Die in the cold
> reaches of space, the old freighter now nothing but a tomb for the
> three of them, lost forever on the outskirts of the galaxy, their
> passing unmourned, their names unremembered.
>
> Dathan, Miramir.
>
> Rey.
>
> <sub><sup>['Star Wars: Shadow of the Sith' exclusive excerpt: Rey's parents showcased in Luke Skywalker-centric story](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/books/2022/05/19/star-wars-shadow-sith-exclusive-excerpt-reys-parents-luke-skywalker/9820101002/)</sup></sub>

Comment: She also doesn't protest (much) when Kylo Ren tells her about her parents (in *Last Jedi*), suggesting that she kind of knew all along.

Comment: I definitely got the impression that when Kylo Ren confronted her with the truth, she accepted it because she knew he was right.

Comment: @Robbert - We won't know until we get the books (in March), but my instinct is that she accepts it as true without any greater insight on her part. I don't think her memory came rushing back.

Answer (score -2):

When Rey was first introduced and kept insisting her parents were coming back, you could tell pretty much everyone was thinking "Uh-huh. Riiiight." Even she seemed half-hearted about it and eventually gave it up. Once she's accepted that her parents weren't coming back, then it's easier to accept the other memory, that they left her with no intention of coming back and never will.

In short, denial. If she refused to accept they weren't coming back, there was no reason to accept the memory they were nobodies her sold her off and left her behind. Once she got over the first hump, then she could accept the latter memory.

Comment: The novels are pretty clear that she doesn't remember them

Comment: A lot of assumptions here, you're assuming that she's in denial which assumes that she does in fact remember. You're also assuming that her parents have left her for good and aren't ever coming back.